# Index of cyclic subgroup $\langle h \rangle$ in a subgroup $H$ with finite index in a finitely generated group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated

Let $\phi: H\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a homomorphism with finite kernel.

Let $h \in H$ such that $\phi(h) \not=0$.

Can someone help me understanding why exactly the cyclic group $\langle h\rangle$ has finite index in $H$ ?

Comment: Because $\langle \phi(h) \rangle$ has finite index in ${\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: By the way, everything that you wrote about $G$ in the first sentence is irrelevant. This question is just about the group $H$ and not about $G$ at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image $\phi(H)$ is cyclic group generated by $\phi(t)$ for some $t\in H$. Let $K$ be the finite kernel. Every element $z\in H$ satisfies $\phi(z)=\phi(t)^k$ for some $k$. Hence $z=t^k s$, $s\in K$. Hence $H=\langle t\rangle K$. Your element $h$ is then equal to $t^cs'$ for some integer $c$ and $s'\in K$. Therefore $\langle h\rangle K=\langle t^c\rangle K$ so $\langle h\rangle$ has finite index in $H$.

Comment: Thank you JCAA. Highly appreciating your answer.

Answer (score 3):

By first isomorphism theorem $\frac{H}{\operatorname{Ker}\phi}\cong \mathbb Z$. Since $h\notin \operatorname{Ker}\phi$, we get $\bar h\in \frac{H}{\operatorname{Ker}\phi} $ generates a non-zero subgroup of $\frac{H}{\operatorname{Ker}\phi}$. Since any non-zero subgorup of $\mathbb Z$ has finite index we get $\langle \bar h \rangle$  has finite index in $\frac{H}{\operatorname{Ker}\phi}$. Thus $\exists \ x_1,x_2\dots,x_n$ such that given $x\in H$, we can write $x=sx_jh^k$ where $s\in \operatorname{Ker}\phi$ for some $j,k$. Since the set $\{sx_j | s\in \operatorname{Ker}\phi ,j=1,2,\dots,n  \}$ is finite, we get $\langle h \rangle $ has finite index in $H$.

Comment: hmm the first isomorphism theorem just implies $H/\operatorname{ker} \phi \cong \operatorname{im}\phi$, doesn't it? If $\phi$ is not surjective, it does not induce an isomorphism $H/\operatorname{ker} \phi \cong \mathbb{Z}$, does it?

Comment: True but any non-zero subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$

Comment: ah, that's neat. thank you!